# Mongodb - com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mongodb

I'm getting this error on connect:

com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream

I have looked at the other SO answers and they do not help.

I can connect from MongoDB compass with LDAP authentication, the same keys that are in the Keystores, the same username/password, and with the commented out options set.

```
@Bean
fun mongoClient(): MongoClient {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/Users/mike/code/certs/truststore.jks")
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "xabcdef")
    System.setProperty("j/Users/mike/code/certs/truststore.jks")
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "xabcdef")

    var optionsBuilder = MongoClientOptions.builder()
    optionsBuilder.sslEnabled(true)
            //.requiredReplicaSetName("rs0")
            //.readPreference(ReadPreference.primary())
            //.sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true)
    val options = optionsBuilder.build()
    var serverAddresses = ArrayList<ServerAddress>()
    serverAddresses.add(ServerAddress("wdcmon201.os.s.net", 27017))
    serverAddresses.add(ServerAddress("wdcmon202.os.s.net", 27017))
    serverAddresses.add(ServerAddress("wdcmon203.os.s.net", 27017))

    var credential = MongoCredential.createPlainCredential("mike", "\$external", "P@\$\$w2291921234!".toCharArray())

    var mongoClient = MongoClient(serverAddresses, credential, options)

    println("Got it")
    return mongoClient
}
```

What gives?  Same machine, same settings/credentials but my Spring Boot app throws that exception with the Spring Boot `CommandLineRunner`

Edit -> It's not a timeout, here is the stack trace, it happens on connect:

```
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:92) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:554) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:425) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:289) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:106) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
```

Comment: Connection may be closed. Try setting max TimeOut or IdelTime https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.Builder.html#maxConnectionIdleTime-int-

Comment: It happens *on connect*, it can't be timing out

Comment: @nayakam - See edit for stack trace